# Как мне написать вывод курсов из базы в Django

Tags: python, django

[image: вот модель и html код]
вот модель и html код
помогите в courses-frame написать вывод всех курсов из базы

Comment: Приложите код текстом, а не фотографией, это облегчит задачу людям, которые захотят вам помочь